# Isolate middle value from $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Not trained in math the solution to this problem is not immediately apparent, plus I am working on a larger problem which I'd rather get to.

I'm trying to isolate the middle value from a $3\times 3$ matrix

Suppose my matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\\ 5 & 7 & 3
\\ 4 & 13 & 9
\\ 9 & 9 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'd like to produce a matrix using linear algebra methods to get

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\\ 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 13 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

I do not want a simple answer like subtract

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\\ 5 & 7 & 3
\\ 4 & 0 & 9
\\ 9 & 9 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Additionally, what is the terminology for this kind of derived matrix if there is one?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\\ 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 13 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: If subtraction isn't allowed, which operations would you allow?

Comment: Is multiplication by other matrices allowed?

Comment: I think it is going to be very hard anyone can help you unless you specify *exactly* what operations you're allowing on your matrix to "isolate", as you call it, that value. It's clear it cannot be the usual linear operations (substracting/summing one multiple of a row/column to other row/column and etc.), as the given matrix is not similar to the one you want to get, so...

Comment: @StefanHansen I don't mind substraction, but it would have to be substraction with a constant matrix.  In other words a matrix that can be reused for various 3x3 matrices.

Comment: @Git Yes.  Anything is allowed accept subtracting the above matrix that I specified.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. For odd $n$, why not take the even row and column term ($a_{22}$ in your example) and place the value on the center value of $nxn$, n-odd, all-zero matrix? This would be much faster than any math operations. What are you doing for even n? Maybe I am missing something in your question. Regards

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Thanks for the edit and links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5&7&3\\4&13&9\\9&9&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&13&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$

The first matrix isolates the middle row and the last isolates the middle column.

Edit: These types of matrices are sometimes called $E_{ij}$, where $i$ is the row and $j$ is the column. So these would be $E_{22}$.

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks John.  Originally I tried doing it the other way, which is A*B*B, where yours is B*A*B.

Comment: No problem. One more thing, if this is the answer you were looking for, could you mark it as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, is there a special name for the 3X3 matrix where there is only a 1 in the middle value (row/column)?

Comment: Sometimes these are called $E_{ij}$, where $i$ is the row and $j$ is the column.